# Table cell transparency or semi-transparency

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to find a way to make a cell transparent or semi-transparent. The below code should work but doesn't:

```html
    <html>
    <style>
        op {
          opacity:0.3;
          filter:alpha(opacity:30)
        }
    
    </style>
    <body background="background.jpg" style="background: black;">
    
    <table border="1" width="100%" height="222">
     <tr>
      <td class="op" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="216">&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    
    </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't properly defined the CSS class, class definition must begin with a dot, in your case `.op`.

Also, your are mixing CSS and HTML attributes, you should only only CSS (note that definitions for HTML tags *don't* start with a dot):

```html
    <html>
    <style>
       body {
         background-image: background.jpg;
         background-color: black; /* for testing without the image*/
       }

       table {
          border: 1px;
          width: 100%;
          height: 222px;
       }

       td {
         height: 216px;
       }

       .op {
         opacity:0.3;
         filter:alpha(opacity:30);
         background-color: #FFFFFF;
       }
    </style>
    <body>
    
    <table>
     <tr>
       <td class="op">&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    
    </body></html>
```